# From Microsoft Power BI to flask web application

Tags: flask, powerbi

Hello so I have created a bunch of visualizations in power BI using sql data.
What I want is to display these results in a flask web application.
Should I store them as images and then display them or should I use an API to do the job ?

Answer (score 1):

You an embed interactive PowerBi Reports, or single visuals in a custom application with [Power BI Embedded Analytics](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-embedded/).

Also there's a new API to render Power BI content to a static image.  See [Export report to PDF, PPTX and PNG files using Power BI REST API (Preview)](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-report-to-pdf-pptx-and-png-files-using-power-bi-rest-api/).

Both of these require the workspace to be deployed on a [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) Capacity, or an [Azure Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/) Capacity.

Comment: After doing some research about your answer, I figured out that there is a problem which is the fact that I am using Power BI's free version which does not give me access to the API

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the contents you can generate PDF of your report and use them in your flask application